# can’t start the ubuntu system after open computer

Tags: 18.04, lenovo

so last week i had the same problem, that i can’t get in to the computer after opening the computer. We took the computer to some experts and they reinstalled the ubuntu system. Im using the computer for two days now but the same problem came out again. I simply cant get into the login page, whenever i turn it off then on it always is at the same page, where there is only the lenovo and ubuntu logo. I don’t know what to do and need to get into the computer as soon as possible.

Comment: Edit to post a picture of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `nomodeset` before `quiet splash` in GRUB.

Enter GRUB: Press Shift when BOIS loading

Edit Boot: Select Ubuntu without pressing enter and press `e` so you can edit boot. And then press Ctrl+x to boot